# React - Problema con modal

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, reactjs

Estoy haciendo mi primera app en React. Resulta que tengo este problema y no sé como solucionarlo. Mi idea es que cuando el cliente haga click en una imagen se abra un modal con la info de la imagen. El problema es que, si bien el modal se abre con el primer click, con los siguientes ya no.

Como lo puedo solucionar?
Muchas gracias!

**Imagen.js**

```
import React, {Fragment, useState} from 'react';
import ModalImg from './Modal';

const Imagen = ({imagen}) => {
    
    const {webformatURL, likes, tags, type, user, userImageURL} = imagen;

    const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
    
    function handleImageOpen(){
        setModalOpen(true);
    }
    
    
    return ( 
        <Fragment>
            <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-12 mb-4">
            <a className="d-block h-100" onClick={() => handleImageOpen()}>
                {(modalOpen === true ? <ModalImg imagen={imagen} /> : null)}
                <img src={webformatURL} className="img-fluid img-thumbnail"></img>
                </a>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
     );
}
```

**Modal.js**

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

const ModalImg = ({ imagen }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose} animation={true}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!
            <p>{imagen.likes}</p>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ModalImg;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución integral sería hacer una función `toggleModal` que cambie el estado al contrario de como se encuentre al momento de ser invocada:

```
function toggleModal() {
    setModalOpen(!modalOpen);
}
```

Y asegúrate de que este componente *padre* controle el estado del componente *hijo*, y lo mejor es que ya tienes el estado que lo controla: `modalOpen`. De esta manera, es muy fácil tener el control:

```
{/* Te recomiendo que dejes este componente fuera del enlace, además de
  * que pasándole la propiedad "isOpen" controlas si se muestra o no: */}
<ModalImg imagen={imagen} isOpen={modalOpen} onToggle={toggleModal} />

<a className="d-block h-100" onClick={toggleModal}>
  <img src={webformatURL} className="img-fluid img-thumbnail"></img>
</a>
```

**Modal.js**:

```
const ModalImg = ({ imagen, isOpen, onToggle }) => {
  return (
    <Modal show={isOpen} onHide={onToggle} animation={true}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!
        <p>{imagen.likes}</p>
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={onToggle}>
          Close
        </Button>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={onToggle}>
          Save Changes
        </Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! me sirvió mucho

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la solución. En **imagen.js** modifiqué asi:

```
    function handleImageOpen(){
        setModalOpen(true);
        if(modalOpen === true){
            setModalOpen(false);
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }
```